# How to print many format strings into window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

After successfully solve this problem [how to print a format string into window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886156/how-to-print-format-string-into-a-window), another problem comes to me.

If there are **many format strings**, how to print them into window? For example below:

```
sprintf(buf, formatString-1...);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)buf);
...
sprintf(buf, formatString-2...);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)buf);
...
sprintf(buf, formatString-3...);
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)buf);
...
```

Notice that **only formatString-3 is printed into window**, while i want to put them all into window. How to do this?(PS: Please Do not use buf concatenate) Thank you!~

Comment: Short of resorting to owner draw rendering for the control, the only way you are going to get all three strings in the control is to concatenate them and include them in a single WM_SETTEXT message. Could you elaborate on why concatenation is not acceptable?

Comment: Which class of window are you using? The first two strings are probably overwritten by your 3rd string so you can only see the last one.

Comment: And are you asking to print multiple lines of texts in the main window?

Comment: @Eric I mean that there are many format strings like formatString-1, formatString-2, formatString-3... How to print them into a window line by line? Thanks.

Comment: @Bill The reason why don't use concatenation is that it will make buf very large. Is there any way to print buf without make buf large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to produce a console-style or log-style window, with multiple lines of text, one after the other?

If so, simplest approach is to pick a control that will do this for you. Something like a static (usually used for labels) typically is only useful for one string at a time. If you want to display more than one line of output, your two main options are:

- Listbox control: add items to the end using LB_ADDSTRING. (You may want to follow that with LB_SETCURSEL or similar to select the last item, so that as items are added to the end, it will scroll to show the last item.)
- Read-only Multi-line Edit control: append text to the end using [the technique outlined here on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/109550). Note that with this approach, you need to supply the "\r\n" yourself to create a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Each `WM_SETTEXT` message overwrites the previous one.  That's why you only observe the effects of the final message.

Although you state that you don't want to concatenate the buffer before sending the `WM_SETTEXT` message, that's the only option with `WM_SETTEXT`.

If you have an edit control then you can insert text using the [`EM_REPLACESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761633%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message.